# NULL parsing JSON with NewtonSoft

Tags: json-deserialization

THE JSON STRING IS:
{ "errcode" : "0",
"errmsg" : SUCCESS",
"responseObject" :{ "result" :[{ "sjmj" : "ABCD",
"zzmmzw" : NULL,
}], "total" : 39 }}

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
        request.Headers.Set("userKey", "vsc30r8f");
        request.Proxy = null;
        request.KeepAlive = false;
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
        request.Accept = "application/json";         

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();        
        Stream myResponseStream = response.GetResponseStream();         

        StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(myResponseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        string retString = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
        myStreamReader.Close();
        myResponseStream.Close();
        if (response != null)
        {
            response.Close();
        }
        if (request != null)
        {
            request.Abort();
        }
```

when i using Newtonsoft method in c#  the code below
**JObject jObj111 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(retString );**
the application exception says"**Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error parsing NaN value**".
or i use
**JObject jObj111 = JObject.Parse(retString )**
the  also application exception says"**Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error parsing NaN value**".
how can i solve the prblem  thanks  very much**

Comment: I USE THIS CODE ALSO NOT WORK  

 var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                    MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
                };

                JObject jObj111 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(retString,settings);

Answer (score 0):

the retString is  : { "errcode" : "0", "errmsg" : SUCCESS", "responseObject" :{ "result" :[{ "sjmj" : "ABCD", "zzmmzw" : NULL}], "total" : 39 }}